# Explanation of convertPosition in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'll explain my scenario first. I have a camera at position (0,0,0) with a node attached in the middle at position (0,0,-20) of the cameras view. Let's say a pointer. The pointer always stays always there. Now what I want is that the camera moves to the pointers position.

How can I get the position of the pointer in world space?

I played around with `convertPositon(_:fromNode)` (and `toNode`) but I could not figure out how it works. Is that function the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, that's the way to go.

```
let toPosition = self.pointerNode.convertPosition(self.pointerNode.position, toNode: nil)
```